# Combinatorics - Building strings with symbols from two alphabets

Tags: combinatorics

Given two alphabets $A$ and $B$ each of cardinality $L$, how many strings of length $2L$ can I build such that

a) No symbol is repeated and

b) No more than two symbols of A appear consecutively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:  you are going to use all the letters.  First how many orders are there of all the symbols from $A$ alone?  How many orders for all the symbols of $B$ alone?  These orders can be paired arbitrarily.  Then we need to choose which of the  $2L$ slots get letters from $A$.  How many ways are there to select those?  You could give all the odd numbered slots to $A$, or ...

Added:  I was thinking no two A's in a row, not no more than two.  The number of configurations starts $2,6,16,45,126,357,1016,\ldots $The series appears to be given in [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A005717), but I don't see how to derive it.  The last entry in comments says this is the series we want.  The way I got the numbers was to define $C(n,m)$ as the number of series of $n A$'s and $m B$'s that don't have three or more successive $A$'s and don't end in $A$, $D(n,m)$ as the number of series of $n A$'s and $m B$'s that don't have three or more successive $A$'s and end in one $A$, $E(n,m)$ as the number of series of $n A$'s and $m B$'s that don't have three or more successive $A$'s and end in two $A$'s, $F(n,m)$ as the total number of series don't have three or more successive $A$'s.  $C(0,0)=1, D(0,0)=0, E(0,0)=0, C(n,m)=C(n,m-1)+D(n,m-1)+E(n,m-1)$

$ D(n,m)=C(n-1,m), E(n,m)=D(n-1,m), F(n,m)=C(n,m)+d(n,m)+E(n,m)$

I just put it all in a spreadsheet, found the numbers above, and looked up in OEIS.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I'd have L! perms for $A$, $L!$ perms for $B$, and $\binom {2L} {L}$ to select slots for A.

Now, if I didn't want two consecutive $A$ symbols, I could put the As in the even or odd slots and then fill everything else, in which case I'd have $2L!(L-1)!$ strings, I think.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to build 2-chunks without counting duplicates, and that's where I'm stuck :/

Comment: Without the restriction on no two A's in a row, it would just be $L!L!\binom{2L}{L}=(2L)!$, as you can just combine the two alphabets and put all the letters in any order. To resolve the restriction, maybe count by hand the number of strings of 3 a's and 3 b's that don't have two a's in a row.  You may see a pattern.

Comment: Well, not two A's in a row should be $2L!L!$. The thing is that I do allow two, but not more.

Comment: Now I think I might be able to solve this if I count those strings that have exactly one 2-chunk, two 2-chunks, and so on until the max number of 2-chunks that L would allow, and then add everything together + the result for no two A's in a row.

Comment: @Jeanne-Kamikaze: I was thinking no two A's in a row, not no more than two.  That makes it much harder, and I now would not think it is a book problem.  I have added an update.